# What is the correct way to use DATE_TRUNC in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to get first day of the year based on the current date. The following query works.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(DATE '2017-01-20', YEAR) as First_day_of_year
```

But, I get syntax error using CURRENT_DATE() in place of the date value.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(DATE CURRENT_DATE(), YEAR) as YEAR
```

> Error: Syntax error: Expected ")" but got identifier "CURRENT_DATE"

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CURRENT_DATE() is already of DATE type so you should use as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), YEAR) as YEAR
```

Comment: Oh.. the Date keyword is actually casting it. Thanks for quick help.

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant do you happen to know what data type YEAR is here? Is it possible to define it as a variable, e.g. DECLARE a ???; SET a = YEAR;

Comment: @riscarrott - feel free to post your question and we will be happy to answer it :o)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176167/how-do-you-declare-day-week-month-quarter-year-etc-as-a-variable :)