# How do you declare `DAY`, `WEEK`, `MONTH`, `QUARTER`, `YEAR` etc. as a variable in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'd like to configure the interval used by my query, but cannot figure out how to declare 
`DAY`, `WEEK`, `MONTH`, `QUARTER`, `YEAR` etc. as a variable.

```sql
DECLARE interval ???; -- What datatype is `DAY`, `MONTH` etc?
SET interval = MONTH;
```

If relevant, my query does something like this:

```sql
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
      DATE_TRUNC('2019-12-11', MONTH),
      DATE_TRUNC('2020-02-19', MONTH),
      INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    )
  ) as date
)
SELECT * FROM dates;
```

And I'd like `MONTH` to be switched out for `WEEK` or `DAY` for example.

Comment: I don't think you can.  Those are syntactic elements, not literal values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare as variables, but this is the best trick I use:

```
DECLARE var_date_option STRING DEFAULT 'MONTH';
```

then use as

```
CASE var_date_option 
    WHEN 'DAY' THEN GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(t.min_date,t.max_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    WHEN 'WEEK' THEN GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(t.min_date,t.max_date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    WHEN 'MONTH' THEN GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(t.min_date,t.max_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  END
```